# report generation tool for zabbix

Tags: report, zabbix

I am working on the Zabbix monitoring tool.
Could any one advise whether we have any tool to generate reports.

Answer (score 1):

Not at my knowledge out-of-the box.

Zabbix is tricky because MySQL backend history tables grow extremely fast and they don't have primary keys. Our current history tables have 440+ million records and we monitor 6000 servers by Zabbix. Single table scan takes 40 minutes on the active server.

So your challenge could be splitted in three smaller challenges:

1. History

Denormalization is the key because joins don't work on huge history tables because you have to join history, items, functions, triggers and hosts tables.

Besides you want to evaluate global and host macros, replace {ITEM.VALUE} and {HOST.NAME} in trigger and item names/descriptions.

BTW there is experimental version of Zabbix which uses Elasticsearch for keeping history and it makes possible sorting and selecting item values by intervals. [Zabbix using Elasticsearch for History Tables](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/appendix/install/elastic_search_setup)

My approach is to generate structures like this for every Zabbix record from history tables and dump them to the document database. Make sure you don't use buffered cursors.

```
    {'dns_name': '',
     'event_clock': 1512501556,
     'event_tstano': '2017-12-05 19:19:16',
     'event_value': 1,
     'host_id': 10084,
     'host_name': 'Zabbix Server',
     'ip_address': '10.13.37.82',
     'item_id': 37335,
     'item_key': 'nca.test.backsync.multiple',
     'item_name': 'BackSync - Test - Multiple',
     'trig_chg_clock': 1512502800,
     'trig_chg_tstamp': '2017-12-05 19:40:00',
     'trig_id': 17206,
     'trig_name': 'BackSync - TEST - Multiple - Please Ignore',
     'trig_prio': 'Average',
     'trig_value': 'OK'
    }
```

2. Current Values

Zabbix APIs are documented pretty good and JSON is handy to dump the structure like proposed for the history. Don't expect Zabbix APIs will return more than 500 metrics / second max. We currently pull 350 metrics / second.

And finally reporting ... There are many options but you have to integrate them:

- Jasper
- Kibana (Elasticsearch)
- Tableau
- Operations Bridge Reporter (Vertica)
- ..

Answer (score 0):

JasperReports - IMHO good "framework" for reports:

- connect it with SQL data connector => you have to be familiar with SQL structure of your Zabbix DB
- more generic solution will be Zabbix API data connector for JasperReports, but you have to code this data connector, because it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Event API](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/api/reference/event) to export data for reporting.

Quoting from the main reference page:

> Events:
>   Retrieve events generated by triggers, network discovery and other
>   Zabbix systems for more flexible situation management or third-party
>   tool integration

Additionally, if you've set up IT Services & SLA, you can use the [Service API](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/api/reference/service/getsla) to extract service % availabilities